# Is a binary produced by CMake generated Make compatible with xcodebuild's one?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, cmake, makefile

I have a C++ project which consists of a several build systems generated by CMake. The one is Make and another one is Xcode's xcodebuild (for an x86_64 system).

The compiler flags are the same for both but confirmed that xcodebuild's one always had **unfamiliar flags that I didn't explicitly set in the CMakeLists by myself** and I assume those flags are the Xcode's default.

And the followings are my concerns:

1. Is it okay to see the both binaries are compatible with each other in logical level? (I've confirmed they were more or less incompatible in the bit layout level.)
2. Would there be any chance to have inconsistency on their behaviors due to the extra flags which are always appended to the xcodebuild project?
3. Which case should I develop software using Make/xcodebuild?

I've confirmed each binary works as I expected through testing with a test project which was also produced during the same build process but don't have any stable evidence that I can see they both are identical.

Comment: Maybe this will help https://outcoldman.com/en/archive/2014/05/02/xcode-and-cmake/

Comment: Which flags are being appended? If there are warnings post those also.